# Angular 9: Creating dynamic ViewContainerRef for looping an array of components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am trying to create a dashboard card-grid page using angular2gridster with different components as the content of each card. The cards are created using a NgFor on an array of object specifying the data about the card, including a property containing the component (as shown below). Somehow, an error shows up on how ViewContainerRef is undefined despite it being fine if I were to move the template out of the NgFor Scope.

```
{
      component: CashflowOverviewComponent,
      title: 'example title',
      visible: true,
      metadata: {
        //XY coordinate in grid
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        //Width and height
        w: 2,
        h: 1,
      },
    },
```

In my HTML, I tried generating the code using an NgFor

```
<div *ngFor="let widget of widgets">
        <ngx-gridster-item *ngIf="widget.visible" class="grid_card" [(x)]="widget['metadata'].x "
            [(y)]="widget['metadata'].y" [(w)]="widget['metadata'].w" [(h)]="widget['metadata'].h">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card_header">
                    <div *ngIf="dragEnabled" class="material-icons card_drag handler_icon drag_icon">drag_indicator
                    </div>
                    <div class="card_title">Card title</div>
                </div>
                <ng-template #cardContent></ng-template>
                {{dynamicComponentGenerator(widget.component)}}
                <div class="card_content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </ngx-gridster-item>
    </div>
```

The code below is how I try to initialize the

```
 @ViewChild("cardContent",{static:true , read: ViewContainerRef}) cardContent: ViewContainerRef;QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;
```

And this is the function I use to try and get the component to show up

```
dynamicComponentGenerator  = (component)=>{
    let factory = this.r.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    this.cardContent.clear();
    let compRef = this.cardContent.createComponent(factory);
  }
```

Comment: You can utilize [ng-dynamic-component](https://github.com/gund/ng-dynamic-component#readme) library.